# цикл while и логические элементы

Tags: python

как написать условия цикла while чтобы он работал пока в тексте не будет # после решетки может быть любой текст

Comment: `while text[0] != '#':`

Comment: @S.Nick, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```
g_str='Это просто текст print(f"Абсолютное значение {complex_number} это {abs_complex_number}") #  Абсолютное значение (3+10j)'
c=0
while True:
   print(g_str[c])
   if g_str[c]=='#':
       break
   c+=1
```